# Woher kommt die Redewendung „eine ruhige Kugel schieben“?

Tags: etymology, idiom

Laut *Duden* ist die Herkunft der umgangssprachlichen Redewendung „eine ruhige Kugel schieben“ (mit der Bedeutung „sich [bei der Arbeit] nicht sonderlich anstrengen müssen“) nicht geklärt. Sie könnte sich vom Kegeln herleiten und sich auf den ruhigen Lauf einer langsamen, mit wenig Anstrengung geworfenen Kugel beziehen.

Gibt es konkrete Hinweise, woher diese Redewendung tatsächlich stammt?

Comment: Bravo, endlich wieder enmal eine gute Frage! +1

Comment: https://www.tagesspiegel.de/sport/kegeln-abgesang-mit-bier-in-der-hand/11718490.html

Answer (score 3):

Dass diese Redewendung ihren Ursprung im Kegeln zu haben scheint, lässt sich eventuell auch über das [Grimmsche Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GK15596#XGK15596) belegen. Hier wird unter der Nummer II 2 b) ein ähnlicher Ausdruck genannt und erläutert, dass "*eine gute Kugel schieben*" die Bedeutung "gut kegeln können" habe.

Eine etwas andere Erläuterung, wo der Ausdruck herkommt, habe ich [hier](https://www.gutefrage.net/frage/woher-stammt-der-ausruck-eine-ruhige-kugel-schieben) gefunden.

Der bei der Antwort angegebene Link "etymologie.tantalosz.de/e.php" ist noch bei [archive.org:](https://web.archive.org/web/20160317003807/http://etymologie.tantalosz.de/e.php)

> Eine ruhige Kugel schieben...natürlich Kegler: Bei diesem geselligen Spiel ist Schnelligkeit nicht unbedingt vonnöten - man kann zwischen den Würfen ganz entspannt plaudern und das eine oder andere Gläschen heben. Fouls sind praktisch unmöglich, es kommt lediglich darauf an, die Kugel nicht zu werfen, sondern sanft und rund, aber mit Schwung auf die Bahn zu setzen - eben »eine ruhige Kugel zu schieben«. Eine sportliche Betätigung, die uns mit zunehmendem Alter immermehr entgegenkommt...

Allerdings geht die dort genannte Erläuterung etwas mehr in die Richtung, dass der Ausdruck üblicherweise negativ gemeint ist:

> "Bei diesem seit dem frühen 20. Jahrhundert immer beliebteren geselligen Spiel ist Schnelligkeit nicht unbedingt vonnöten - man kann zwischen den Würfen ganz entspannt plaudern und das eine oder andere Gläschen heben. Fouls sind praktisch unmöglich, es kommt lediglich darauf an, die Kugel nicht zu werfen, sondern sanft und rund, aber mit Schwung auf die Bahn zu setzen - eben »eine ruhige Kugel zu schieben«."

Mit dem Verweis auf die Langsamkeit und Gemütlichkeit klingt die Erläuterung ganz plausibel.

Comment: Das stimmt, und daran hatte ich nicht gedacht, aber früher sicher schon! Aber die Schützen bei uns  machen es auch so. Da wird sogar noch ein Würstchen gebrätelt, zwischendurch.

Answer (score 1):

Eine "Kugel schieben", ob ruhig oder unruhig, is keinesfalls erst ab dem 20. Jahrhundert vom Kegeln abgeleitet, wie zum Beispiel hier behauptet:

> [Begriffsursprung:](https://www.wortbedeutung.info/eine_ruhige_Kugel_schieben/)
> Die erst im 20. Jahrhundert entstandene Wendung entstammt dem Kegelspiel. Da die Kegelbahn sehr glatt ist, bedarf es keiner besonders großen Kraftanstrengung, um die Kugel ins Rollen zu bringen. So wurde dieser Vorgang zu einem Sinnbild von Mühelosigkeit.

Kegeln ist auch nicht erst seit dem 20. Jahrhundert  beliebt:

> [image] (1774)
> Deutsch: Vergnügungen der Kinder. a) Soldatenspiele. Der Bogenschütze. [Die Kegelschieberinnen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:Chodowiecki_Basedow_Tafel_5_a.jpg), der Aufsetzer. (Beschreibung lt. Quelle)

Wobei im [Grimmschen Wörterbuch *zwei* Einträge](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB//wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GK15597) zu beachten sind:

> für schieben galten oder gelten auch bair. scheiben (das mhd. schîben u. a) Schm. 3, 307, werfen, schieszen, bôʒen
>
> b) die kugel hin schieben. Ringwald klagt über häufigen zwiespalt zwischen pfarr und caplan (diaconen), die
> aus dem text ein ursach brechn,
> einander auf die haut zu stechn.
> welchs sie ein weil verborgn treibn,
> bis sie die kugel gar hinscheibn
> und von der canzel öffentlich
> gar ergerlich thun schelten sich. laut. warh. 362 (323),
> also von feindschaft, die endlich zum offenen kampfe übergeht. man müszte das gemeinte spiel genau kennen, um die redensart ganz zu verstehn.

Bei Adelung

> [Einschießen](https://lexika.digitale-sammlungen.de/adelung/lemma/bsb00009131_7_0_741)  , verb. irreg. act. S. Schießen. 1) Hinein schießen, d. i. schieben, in welchem Verstande die Bäcker das Brot einschießen, wenn sie den zu Broten geformten Teig auf der Brotschiebe in den Ofen schieben.
>
> [Der Kegelschub](https://lexika.digitale-sammlungen.de/adelung/lemma/bsb00009132_6_0_638), [1531-1532] des -es, plur. die -e. 1) Das Schieben der Kegel, das Kegelspiel; ohne Plural. 2) Der Ort, wo Kegel geschoben werden. In beyden Fällen im gemeinen Leben auch der Boßelschub.

Oder auch:

> Joseph-Alois Ditscheiner: "Grammatisch-orthographisch-stilistisches Handwörterbuch der deutschen Sprache. 2. Aufl", Karl Woigt jun., 1870, S373:
> [mit einer Kugel schieben](https://books.google.de/books?id=ooSGA7G5nbMC&pg=PA373)

Es scheint als würden Interpretationen zur Herkunft, die sich auf langsam und gemütlich stützen, die ursprüngliche Bedeutung von schieben als 'werfen'/'schießen', zugunsten der aktuellen Bedeutung vernachlässigen.

Die Ergänzung 'ruhig' scheint ursprünglich eher eine Zielsicherheit auszudrücken und erst sekundär zu gemütlich umgedeutet worden zu sein.

Die ruhige Kugel wird von jemandem geschoben, nicht: die Kugel wird von einem ruhigen Spieler geschoben.

Comment: Willst Du damit sagen, dass das Sprichwort weniger bedeutet, dass man einen laschen Job hat (o.dgl.) als dass man ihn souverän beherrscht (was ja korrelieren kann)?

Answer (score 0):

Versuch mal beim Bowling  mit einer unruhigen Kugel ein Babeli oder einen Kranz zu kegeln.

Die ruhige Kugel strebt ihrem Ziel entgegen, die unruhige Kugel driftet ins Abseits.

https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/eine_ruhige_Kugel_schieben

Ich habe mal beim französischen Petanque-Spiel nachgeschaut:

*Quelle est l'importance du mental ?
Si vous avez envie de bien jouer, c'est que vous avez déjà la passion du jeu. Attention, toutefois. Sous des dehors débonnaires, la pétanque est un jeu éprouvant pour les nerfs et la tension qui en résulte peut vous faire perdre tous vos moyens. Une règle, celle des 4 **C** : **c**alme, **c**oncentration, **c**ombativité et **c**onfiance en soi.*

"Wie wichtig ist der Verstand?
Wenn du gut spielen willst, liegt es daran, dass du bereits die Leidenschaft des Spiels hast. Petanque ist ein nervenaufreibendes Spiel, und die Spannung, die daraus resultiert, kann dazu führen, dass Sie alle Mittel verlieren. Eine Regel, die von 4 C:  calme, concentration, combativité et confiance (Ruhe, Konzentration, Kampfgeist und Selbstvertrauen.)"

**Ruhe, Konzentration, Kampfgeist und Selbstvertrauen.**

https://www.letelegramme.fr/soir/petanque-comment-etre-un-champion-sur-le-terrain-de-boules-27-07-2018-12038328.php

Die o.g. Redensart auf französisch übersetzt heisst dann: 
Se la couler douce und bedeutet in etwa "dolce vita", was letztlich mit dem 
Petanque-Spiel zusammenfällt:

Si la bière coule parfois à flots et l'eau s'écoule des montagnes, les verbes 'couler' et "s'écouler" ne s'appliquent pas qu'aux liquides et autres flux ; ils ont aussi une acception temporelle, puisque depuis le XVe siècle, on dit que le temps s'écoule et depuis le XVIIe, on parle de "couler des jours heureux".

Ainsi, une vie est bien du temps qui passe, qui s'écoule. Or il se trouve que notre expression, apparue au XIXe siècle, est simplement une forme elliptique de "couler une vie douce" (philosophie que nos amis italiens ont exprimé sous la forme "dolce vita" ou "vie douce"?).

d.h.:

**wenn die Tage ruhig fliessen und die Kugel ruhig rollt ...**

Comment: Gegen diese Interpretation spricht, dass die Aussage "Er schiebt eine ruhige Kugel" in der Regel nicht positiv gemeint ist.

Comment: Es kann natürlich sein, dass da ein paar locker beim Kegeln sind, während der eigentliche Auftrag lautet, die Nadel im Heuhaufen zu suchen!

Comment: ich lösche meine Anwort und gebe den Punkt an IQV. Wobei im Schützenverein oft dasselbe gilt!

Comment: ich habe meine Antwort wieder undeleted. Sie scheint mir gar nicht so schlecht zu sein.

Answer (score -4):

Kein Wissen, nur eine Hypothese:

Vielleicht von Sisyphos?

Der Steinblock, den dieser wieder und wieder den Berg hinaufzuwälzen hat, wird in der bildenden Kunst seit ca. 2500 Jahren als eine mehr oder weniger hübsche Kugel dargestellt.

Wer Nachweise sucht: Das Internet gibt unzählige her. Die alle anzukucken, wäre eine echte Sisyphusarbeit. Hier sind mal zwei:

Vasenbild aus dem Jahre 530 vuZ:

[image: Vasenbild aus dem Jahre 530 vor Christus]

Sisyphos gemalt von Franz von Stuck, 1920:

[image: Sisyphos gemalt von Franz von Stuck, 1920]

Die Logik wäre dann die: Sisyphos hat eine sehr unruhige Kugel zu schieben, nämlich eine, die immer wieder den Berg hinunterwill. Der Beamte hingegen (nach volkstümlicher Meinung, nehmen wir einmal dieses verbreitete, wenn auch sicherlich falsche Bild) schiebt eine **ruhige** Kugel: Er hat es nicht so schwer. Seine Arbeit läuft ihm nicht davon.

Oder aber man nimmt statt der Mythologie die Zoologie her und leitet das Kugelschieben vom Skarabäus-Käfer her. Aber ich vermute mal, zwischen ihm und Sisyphos gibt es auch eine enge Verwandtschaft.

Anmerkung noch: Der entsprechende Eintrag in Wikipedia sowie bei www.redensarten-index.de behauptet, der Spruch gehe auf das Kegelspiel zurück. Ich finde das eine etwas zu seichte Erklärung. Insbesondere bieten sie nicht mehr als die Behauptung, jedoch keinerlei Belege etwa in Form früher Nachweise des Auftretens des Spruches in Verbindung mit dem Aufkommen von Kegelbahnen.

Comment: Nun schiebt Sysiphos aber eher keine ruhige Kugel, sondern seine Tätigkeit ist eher anstrengend und wegen ihrer Sinnlosigkeit außerdem noch frustrerend.

Comment: @RHa - Habe den Beitrag um eine Erläuterung dazu ergänzt.

Comment: „Aufkommen von Kegelbahnen“ - die sind älter als die moderne deutsche Sprache.

Comment: Etwas zu bildungsbürgerlich für meinen Geschmack, aber als volksetymologischer Erklärungsversuch *mindestens* ebenso gut belegt, plausibel und überzeugend wie "von der Faulheit beim Kegeln ab dem 20. Jh".

Comment: Abwertung vonnöten hier? Wir sollten die Entwicklung von Theorien nicht so runterputzen; gerade im Bereich der Etymologie.

Comment: Man spricht nicht davon, dass man Kugeln einen Berg raufschiebt, auch die Bilder stützen diese Ansicht nicht. Das erste Bild zeigt Tragen, das zweite Wuchten. Und dass die Kugel den Berg runterzurollen droht, wird durch das Wort "unruhig" nicht ausgedrückt.